# How to create an instance of dbContext in Entity Framework Core Migrations?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is it possible to create an instance of my dbContext in my Entity Framework Core migrations? Is this a supported feature? I can't seem to get an instance via `Migration` or `MigrationBuilder`

Comment: What would be the use case?

Comment: Moving data from one table to another and then making some references from the old table to the new table. I know can do it using a SQL in the migration file but I'd rather not.

Comment: @burnt1ce Rather yes - `Sql` is indeed your only option. `DbContext` cannot be used inside migrations because at the time of migration the model is different than that final model set up in `OnModelCreating`.